# Magic 8 ball in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am looking to create a kind of "magic eight ball" website. [This is an example](https://askhelixfossil.com/) of what I am thinking of. How can I write code to mimic this random answer effect?

Comment: Have you started on any code that you'd like to share and receive help on?

Comment: Software or off-site resource recommendations are off-topic on Stack Overflow _and_ your question is too broad: a better version of this question would have some _already existing non-working code and a specific problem_ with it that you can’t fix by yourself (after research). Please read the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and some relevant help pages ([What is on topic here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can select random answers from an array and display them. Suppose you have an array named `answers`. You can select one at random like this:

```
var answer = answers[Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length)];
```

Then you can insert the answer into an element named `answerContainer`, for example:

```
document.getElementById('answerContainer').innerHTML = answer;
```

Here is a demonstration:

```js
var answers = [
  'Maybe.', 'Certainly not.', 'I hope so.', 'Not in your wildest dreams.',
  'There is a good chance.', 'Quite likely.', 'I think so.', 'I hope not.',
  'I hope so.', 'Never!', 'Fuhgeddaboudit.', 'Ahaha! Really?!?', 'Pfft.',
  'Sorry, bucko.', 'Hell, yes.', 'Hell to the no.', 'The future is bleak.',
  'The future is uncertain.', 'I would rather not say.', 'Who cares?',
  'Possibly.', 'Never, ever, ever.', 'There is a small chance.', 'Yes!'];

document.getElementById('answerButton').onclick = function () {
var answer = answers[Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length)];
    document.getElementById('answerContainer').innerHTML = answer;
};
```

```css
p, input, button {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}
input {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<p> How can I help you today? </p>

<input type="text" placeholder="enter a question"></input>

<button id="answerButton"> Answer me </button>

<p id="answerContainer"></p>
```

Comment: This is perfect but for me it shows the code in text above the element. Any way I could fix this. Also, any NEATER looking ways?

Comment: The code is visible because my intent and Stack Overflow's intent is to show you the code. After you put the code into an HTML file, the user will only see the visible HTML elements. The user sees the contents of the inner frame that shows up when you click on "Run code snippet". I'm not sure what you mean about doing it neater. Are you asking about page styling? You can style the page to your heart's content using CSS. Here, I slapped this together for you: http://michaellaszlo.com/so/magic-eight-ball/

Comment: If you're satisfied, would you mind accepting my answer?

Comment: Sorry, I am satisfied, thanks!

Comment: Then would you please accept my answer so that I can get reputation points? You have to click the checkmark next to my answer.